OS apps reordering feature in Flutter
I want to implement a reordering feature just like OS reordering we have in Android or IOS, This feature requires multi-page reordering which I was not able to find in Flutter packages.
Example :


The ReorderableListView widget allows you to reorder items in a list by dragging and dropping them. plus you can use draggable grid view package.
check following links for further assistance:

ReorderableListView example

draggable gridview package



Thank for you your answer, But this is not what I expected.
I need pagination and page behavior which IOS and Android have.
I was not able to find such package and I think I will need to add those behavior myself.

i am not sure if I understand your question well. but probably you will need to implement it manually as you mentioned.
